# Printing values from a list to a plot for each ID

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, r-plotly

I have a list each value in the list has an ID assigned to a number. I would like to have the values appear on a plot for each ID. I wasn't sure how to reproduce the plots, so I'll try and explain it. I have a plot for each ID, and I would like to have the values appear as text on the plots (let's just say the plots of line plots). So for the plot of `ID` "A" I would like both `1` and `1` to appear on the plots because in the list both `A`s are assigned the value `1`. For `ID` "B" I would like both `2` and `2` to appear on the plot for `ID` "B", and so forth for the other `ID`s.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"),1000)
ID <- rep(c("A","B","C", "D", "E"), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df1 <- df %>% group_split(ID)
l <- list(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
l <- setNames(l, c(unique(df$ID), unique(df$ID)))
```

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you create sample output for one of the plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `geom_text()` a `label` aesthetic, which will get separated by `facet_wrap()` nicely for you, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(47L)

df <- tibble(
  date = rep_len(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by = "days"), 1000),
  x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
  y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
  ID = rep(c("A","B","C", "D", "E"), 200)
)

id_labels <- tibble(
  ID = rep(unique(df$ID), 2),
  id_val = rep(1:5, 2)
) %>% 
  # make desired labels for each facet
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(label = paste(ID, id_val, sep = ": ", collapse = '\n'))

df %>% 
  gather(var, val, x:y) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, val)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = var)) + 
  geom_text(
    # hardcode position
    aes(x = as.Date('2010-04-01'), y = 500000, label = label),
    data = id_labels  # pass in data frame of labels
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ID)
```

[image: facetted plot with annotations on each facet]

Comment: If I wanted to use the list `l` to create the label date frame, how would I go about doing this? The values in my actual data set has different values for each `ID` so I would like to learn how I could create the labels with the list `l`, and to print the values directly from the list.

Comment: ggplot only accepts data in data frames, so you have to have a data frame. To turn `l` into `id_labels`, you could do `id_labels <- enframe(unlist(l), 'ID', 'id_val') %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(label = paste(ID, id_val, sep = ": ", collapse = '\n'))` or equivalent.